# Angular 2 issue in accessing componet property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

i am new in Angular 2 and trying to develop a project with basic CRUD functionality. 
I am facing an issue that i have a `User` component and trying to access it's property in `ngAfterViewInit` hook, but it's showing `undefined`.

Here is code of `User` component.

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit 
{

private users: User[];
private userRoles;

ngOnInit(){
           //get users from service
           this.getUserDetails();
        }
ngAfterViewInit() {
               console.log(this);
               console.log(this.users);
        }
getUserDetails() {    
            this._userService.getUsers().subscribe(users => this.users = users);            
         }    
}
```

Below is screen shots of console. I can see that Object has property `users` but it shows `undefined` in console.
[image: Object out put] 
[image: console]

Please give suggestion if i missed anything.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check user property inside `getUserDetails`. You can use `users` property in your template. Check [component lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#hooks-purpose-timing) to get better idea about component lifecycle.

```
getUserDetails() {    
  this._userService.getUsers().subscribe((users) => {
    this.users = users;
    console.log(this.users);
  });
}
```

Comment: it's showing data in `getUserDetails()`, but still `undefined` in `ngAfterViewInit()`

Comment: what's your use case for which you need to check `users` inside `ngAfterViewInit` ?

Comment: I want to initialize a bootstrap datatable in hook `initTable($tableUsers, columnsUsers, this.users, $removeUser, $toolbarUsers);`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not angular 2 issue...
This is typescript issue accessing **this** instance **globally** .

We can do this by using let and declaring variable in typescripts...
When javascript object assigned is cloned to other object then changes made to one is automatically passed to other

So this issue also **arrises** when we want to access typescript **this** object inside **jquery** functions

```
let _this = this;
something.each(function() {
    console.log(_this); // the lexically scoped value
    console.log(this); // the library passed value
});
```